# Error with pathForResource: inDirectory

Tags: swift

I created subfolder "Sounds" and added file "backstage.mp3"

This is working good:

```
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("backstage", ofType: "mp3")!
```

But when I try to add **inDirectory**

```
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("backstage", ofType: "mp3", inDirectory: "Sounds")!
```

it's crashed with fatal error:

*fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the way you imported the files.

In the pop-up window make sure you select "Copy items if needed" and "Create Folder References".

Otherwise the subfolder doesn't actually exist in the app's bundle.